# How do I set both NOPASSWD and SETENV on the same line in sudoers?

Tags: linux, sudo

In the sudoers file, how can I use multiple Tag_Specs on the same line.

Normally if I don't want to ask for a password I will do something like this:

```
who  where = (aswhom) NOPASSWD: commands
```

I want to use the `SETENV` tag so that users can preserve environment variables. This works fine like this:

```
who  where = (aswhom) SETENV: commands
```

From the sudoers(5) man page:

```
    Tag_Spec ::= ('NOPASSWD:' | 'PASSWD:' | 'NOEXEC:' | 'EXEC:' |
                  'SETENV:' | 'NOSETENV:' | 'LOG_INPUT:' | 'NOLOG_INPUT:' |
                  'LOG_OUTPUT:' | 'NOLOG_OUTPUT:')
```

I can't see how I can use multiple tags on the same entry. I would both like to use `NOPASSWD` and `SETENV` on the same line.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The same commands:

```
who  where = (aswhom) NOPASSWD:SETENV: commands
```

The different commands:

```
who  where = (aswhom) NOPASSWD: command1, SETENV: command2
```

Comment: Thank you, works as expected. It's obvious now but I couldn't see it before.

Comment: @quanta  What if this isn't working as expected?  I have `who  where = (aswhom) NOPASSWD:SETENV: commands` but I'm still being prompted for a password

Comment: @ColoradoTechie seems like it's a different case, please provide details in a separate question.